# Get closest element by traversing DOM backwards

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to get a DOM element with jQuery but i want to only look backwards in the DOM.

So suppose i have the following HTML structure:

```
<div id="content">
    <div id="first-module" class="module">
        <h3>Some Module</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum... </p>

        <div id="some-other-content">
            <div id="second-module" class="module">
                <h3>Some other module</h3>
                <p>Dolor sit amet...</p>
                <button class="trigger">Trigger 1</button>
            </div>
        </div>

        <button class="trigger">Trigger 2</button>
        <div id="third-module" class="module">
            <h3>Another module</h3>
        </div>
    <div>
</div>

$('.trigger').click(function() {
    // Traverse DOM to find closest .module class
});
```

So when i click on the `Trigger 1` button i want it to find the `div` with ID `second-module`.

When i click on `Trigger 2` i want it to find the `div` with ID `first-module` and **not** `second-module`, because it's nested deeper than the `Trigger 2` button is.

Is there a jQuery function for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using [.closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/)

```
$('.trigger').click(function() {
    $(this).closest('.module');
});
```

Comment: Nice, for some reason i though `closest` would go both ways. But this is perfect.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, we do have [.closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) for this:

```
$('.trigger').click(function() {
    // Traverse DOM to find closest .module class
    var id = $(this).closest('.module').attr('id');
    alert(id);
});
```

[**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/gPh7c/)

Answer (score 1):

Another way to access it is using  [parent selector](http://api.jquery.com/parent/)

```
$('.trigger').click(function() {
   console.log($(this).parent('.module').attr('id'));
    // Traverse DOM to find closest .module class
});
```

Comment: Be carefull though with `parent()` this returns zero or more elements unlike `closest` which returns zero or one element. This also mean that `parent` traverses back to the document root, unlike `closest`. So `parent` might give too much overhead when you only need one element.

Comment: @w00 i think you are talking about parents() but i am using parent. The .parents() and .parent() methods are similar, except that the latter only travels a single level up the DOM tree.

Comment: Ah you're right, i thought `parent()` did this but it's `parents()`. My bad.